# how to zip up a visual studio 2012 web service solution folder so that it can be run on another machine

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012

i'm using visual studio to make a webservice as well as to make a couple applications that use some simple webservices. our teachers wants us to zip up the solution folder and then turn that in but im having trouble.

I went to where vs stores projects and i zipped the one i needed but the WCF web service doesn't open. It says the project file or web cannot be found.

Comment: A few lines of your question confuse me. "where vs stores projects". VS stores _any_ project _where you tell it to_. It doesn't store them all in one spot unless you mean the default directory. "the WCF web service doesn't open". How do you open a WCF web service? What are you "opening" it with?

Chances are, if your web service is named "Foo" then you want to find the folder named "Foo" that contains Foo's `Web.config` and zip that entire thing up.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem you're having is that your solution directory and solution file are stored in the default location (Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects), but your project files are stored in another location. If you create a project from scratch this shouldn't happen, but there are a number of ways your project could have wound up in this configuration, so you're not necessarily doing anything wrong.

Here's how to fix it so that you can deliver the entire solution or solutions to your teacher:

1. Open up your solution in Visual Studio.
2. Open the Solution Explorer View either from the View menu or by typing Ctrl-Alt-L. If it's already open, just select it.
3. Select the first project in Solution Explorer.
4. Open the Properties View either from the View menu or by typing Ctrl-W, P. If it's already open, just select it.
5. You should see that the Project has 2 properties: Project File and Project Folder. The Project Folder is what you're looking for: this is the location of the project.
6. Open Windows Explorer and find the project folder. Copy it and paste a copy inside of the solution folder.
7. Delete the project from your solution by selecting the project and hitting the delete key.
8. Right-click the Solution file and select *Add->Existing Project...* from the context menu. Then select the project that you copied. Make sure you select the copy in the solution folder, not the original copy that is outside of the solution.
9. Repeat steps 3 through 8 for all projects in the solution.

Once you're done, you'll have multiple copies of your projects on the same disk, so it might be a good idea to archive and delete the old copies of the projects so that you're sure you don't accidentally work on the wrong project copy.

I'd recommend you bringing this issue up with your teacher in order to figure out how your projects wound up in this configuration. I'm sure your teacher won't mind and it could be helpful to others in the class.